# Google Maps markers not showing on Internet Explorer

Tags: google-maps

I have a google map that adds multiple markers on it and the InfoWindow contains some custom html in it. ([here is a live example](http://www.lakecoeurdalene.com/on-the-water/marinas/))

The map and its markers show fine in all browsers except Internet Explorer. The markers never show. However, the funny thing is, if I press F12, get in developer mode to try to figure out what is going on, the markers show just fine. Then I exit developer mode and it still shows just fine.

Has anyone else ran into a similar situation? I have no idea what to do to make the marker show the first time. (I tried adding a timeout to give the maps time to load before adding the markers, but that didn't work)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple answer, not intuitive. Comment out `console.log` in the file `/static//places/js/google_maps.js`. I tested in IE 9.

Comment: Oh man, I would have never figured that out on my own. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

In my case the problem was that the link to create the marker is not found in IE:

```
new google.maps.MarkerImage("http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=%E2%80%A2|");
```

I changed that link for that, and found it!

```
new google.maps.MarkerImage("http://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=%E2%80%A2|");
```

Note the difference in the base URL.

Comment: It really helps. "chart.apis.google.com" results in the certificate error (even with http, not https; i'm not sure why) in IE11.